# Refresh a page with a condition

Tags: php

How can I refresh a page based on condition. For example, I have a value from a table, if the value from that table is NULL the refresh should not execute. If there is a value, the page should be refreshed. Thank you!

```
<?PHP

$db_con = oci_connect('system', 'password1', 'dashboard');

$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
$rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 30;

$sort = isset($_POST['sort']) ? strval($_POST['sort']) : 'NGM_ID';
$order = isset($_POST['order']) ? strval($_POST['order']) : 'asc';
if($page == 1)
    $offset = (($page-1)*$rows) - 1;
else
    $offset = ($page-1)*$rows;

$result = array();


$sql = "select TIMESTAMPEND from DASH_TRANSMITSTATE order by TIMESTAMPSTART desc";
$stid = oci_parse($db_con, $sql);
oci_execute($stid);
$row = oci_fetch_row($stid);

if ($row[0] != null) { ?> 
<script> location.reload(true); </script> 
<?php }

... // code php
```

Comment: php is only ran when the user access it. You can't refresh a page, unless a users does an action. You need JS.

Comment: `<?php if(!is_null($condition){ ?> <script> location.reload(); </script> <?php } ?>`

Comment: @dan: why bother? that code would be runing on the server. why force a page reload when you're in the middle of the building the page anyways?

Comment: I update the question with my code. Does not work!

Comment: You have a deep architecture problem, if you realy want to. Describe the background for this question, so we can provide a better solution. What is the problem with Code @Dan provided? if you don't want to use `!is_null` you should use `!==` instead of `!=` Operator

Comment: I have a html page and a php one. I take the data from 1 table and if a column is null I don't want to make the refresh. You have my code above!

Comment: @eu127 no, you haven't said something new. Look: we need to understand the real problem domain, not the implementation you have current in mind, which we all agree, it is realy bad practise. What are you trying to achieve? Why you think a reload would be the only option? What is the difference if you reload, to not reload again?